# ancient natural poison

Tags: poisons

I'm looking for a natural hallucinogen
available in northern Europe in 500 BCE.

I have a bog body that's ingested this prior to death.
i want something not detectable in the bog body in 2020.
Some chemistry that doesn't preserve well

Ergot can be detected in a bog body.
What about black henbane, belladonna, fly agaric, cannabis, opium, datura, sweet flag, mandrake, ... some kinda mushroom?

Answer (score 4):

I'd try [muscarine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muscarine). It is found in mushrooms and is water soluble, so it could have been assumed as a liquid (e.g. traditionally, the urine of a shaman), leaving no telltale traces in the stomach. I strongly suspect that the ergot you're referring to might have been detected by analyzing the grass, herb, or flour residue in the stomach; the spores would be recognizable with the aid of an electron scanning microscope.

But lacking any solid traces, such an analysis would return negative.

Also, the compound would be completely diffused out of the bog body over such a long time.

Comment: [Amanita muscaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amanita_muscaria) is common enough in these parts, and this would have been my suggestion as well. Usually not lethal, but not recommended in your diet :-)

Comment: Sounds like a good possibility.

Comment: I need to look at what kind of analysis would be possible in the bog bodies.  It seems perfectly logical the muscarine would be overlooked in analysis up to now.